# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: functionName

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there is so much topic with this subject but none of those topics solved my problem.

I have a javascript code and there is several function in it, after about an hour I finally found all function that is defined under a special function doesn't work and the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: functionName" will appear and all the other that is defined on top of that special function is work properly.
My problem is that I can't find out what's wrong with this special function that causes this problem ... can anyone help me ?

Here is that special function :

```
function shift(btn) {
if (!shiftPressed) {
    document.getElementById("keyShift1").style.background = "rgb(180,50,0)";
    document.getElementById("keyShift2").style.background = "rgb(180,50,0)";
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        var id = "key" + String.fromCharCode(i);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).value.toUpperCase();
    }
    document.getElementById("key~").innerHTML = "`";
    shiftPressed = !shiftPressed;

} else {
    document.getElementById("keyShift1").style.background = "black";
    document.getElementById("keyShift2").style.background = "black";

    document.getElementById("key~").innerHTML = "~";
    if (!capsPressed) {
        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            var id = "key" + String.fromCharCode(i);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).value.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    shiftPressed = !shiftPressed;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: yes ... for example if a function with name test() is defined under this function ... then i see this error :
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a curly brace at the end of the function

It should be

```
function shift(btn) {
    if (!shiftPressed) {
        document.getElementById("keyShift1").style.background = "rgb(180,50,0)";
        document.getElementById("keyShift2").style.background = "rgb(180,50,0)";

        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            var id = "key" + String.fromCharCode(i);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).value.toUpperCase();
        }

        document.getElementById("key~").innerHTML = "`";
        shiftPressed = !shiftPressed;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("keyShift1").style.background = "black";
        document.getElementById("keyShift2").style.background = "black";
        document.getElementById("key~").innerHTML = "~";

        if (!capsPressed) {
            for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
                var id = "key" + String.fromCharCode(i);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).value.toLowerCase();
            }
        }

        shiftPressed = !shiftPressed;
    }
}
```